# Running Flask on Twisted - TypeError: __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, twisted

I have a really simple flask app that I am trying to host using twisted. I keep running into this error and cannot find any simple example doing this. The error is:

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 
'environ' and 'start_response'
```

My Flask code is test01.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

And I startup the app by calling:

```
PYTHONPATH=. twistd web --class=test01.app
```

I am sure I must be missing something simple but can't seem to find a simple working example anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `--wsgi` instead of `--class`. `--class` requires Resource subclass.